# How do I change newapa: In (editorname) (ed.) to I (editorname) (red.), in bibliography

Tags: bibtex, natbib

I have this reference in my bibliography:

> Højholdt, A. (2016).  Tværprofessionalitet.  **In** A. Højholdt **(Ed.)**,Tværprofessionelt  samarbejd  i  teori  og  praksis.  (2.  udgave,  3.  oplag). København:Hans Reitzels Forlag.

I would like to change it to:

> Højholdt, A. (2016).  Tværprofessionalitet.  **I** A. Højholdt **(Red.)**,Tværprofessionelt  samarbejd  i  teori  og  praksis.  (2.  udgave,  3.  oplag). København:Hans Reitzels Forlag.

My bibfile has the entries:

```
@incollection{Hoejholdt16tvaerprofessionalitet,
Author = "Andy Højholdt",
title = "Tværprofessionalitet",
editor = "Andy Højholdt",
booktitle = "Tværprofessionelt samarbejd i teori og praksis. (2. udgave, 3. oplag)",
Year = "2016",
Publisher = "København{:} Hans Reitzels Forlag",
}
```

My main documents have this for the bibliography:

```
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{hyperref}
```

----in document---

```
\renewcommand{\bibname}{Litteraturliste} 
\bibliography{bibliografi}
\pagenumbering{gobble}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Litteraturliste}
```

Comment: As far as I can see this can only be achieved by modifying (a copy of!) `newapa.bst`. You have to find, copy and rename the file. Then you can open it with your favourite text editor and find the strings "Ed.", "Eds." as well as "In" and "in" and replace them with the appropriate Danish translation.

Comment: I use overleaf.com to write, do you know if its possible to do here?